# UIWebView, Trouble with opening links

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

When I go to a website and click on a specific link in UIWebView, the UIWebView goes blank. When I open the same website in Safari and click on the link, it opens a new tab. How do I fix this so that when the link is clicked in UIWebView, the page actually appears? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that might help:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView?
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var url = NSURL(string:"http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=AAPL&t=6m&q=l&l=on&z=s&p=m50,m200")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to show a working code example.  If this one works for you then maybe your code had an issue.